# Search inside Java Files Linux in a pattern

Tags: java, linux, shell, grep, find

I am new to Linux search. But need to write a script or a command to search inside all the java files in a folder (can have other directories inside) which follow a specific pattern.

```
public class ${key} extends ${key}
```

where the variable `${key}` is the name of the file.

**Some examples:**
Let the name of the file be Foo.java.
Search pattern: `public class Foo extends foo`.
Other variations: `public class Foo extends com.example.foo`.

This script needs to be later on adapted to perform other Java Files content search.

**EDIT :**
I need pick up the `${key}` as well i.e I need to store the filename without extension or path and then insert it into the command. Something like we do (in c/java): `"public class" + fname + " extends " + " fname "`

**Output** can be like:
`./src/com/foo/bar.java:public class foobar extends com.foo.foobar`

Comment: it could be done by shell(grep, awk..). however, it is not safe. Because java syntax allows the class definition to have line breaks, comments.... For quick and dirty.. well, grep helps. But if you want to make it for long-term use or some critical purpose... you better think it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at using the find command and piping it to a grep command.

```
find /directory -iname *.java | grep -e "class ${key}"
```

you can do something similar to find classes that extend it as well.  You can look up regex to find how to make it more flexible for new lines and other white space characters.

Comment: should be "find /dir -name *.java - exec grep searchPattern {} \;"

Comment: How should I pick up the ${key} which is the most important part. Need to store the filename without extension or path and then insert it into the command. Something like we do (in c/java): `"public class" + fname + " extends " + " fname "`.